# read just a number from file and decrement in batch file

Tags: batch-file, file-io, decrement

Here's the whole issue.  I'm trying to read the IP address of a given adapter on a computer, decrement the last digit by 1, and add the new IP address as a route.  I so far have managed to extract the IP address in the following manner:

```
netsh interface ip show config name=15| findstr "IP Adress" > C:\ip.txt
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%F in (c:\ip.txt) do echo %%F > c:\ipstripped.txt
for /f "tokens=2 delims=1" %%F in (C:\ipstripped.txt) do echo 1%%F >c:\ipdigits.txt
```

this gets me a file that has the IP address in it, but also blank spaces and possibly a carriage return at the end of the line.  Then I run:

```
for /f "tokens=4 delims=." %%F in (C:\ipdigits.txt) do echo %%F >c:\lastdig.txt
```

this gets me a file that has just the last digit in it, but also seems to have extra characters..  At that point, when I try to run:

```
for /f "delims=" %%f in (c:\lastdig.txt) DO Set count=%%f
echo %count%
(
set /a %count%-=1
   echo %count%
)
echo %count%> C:\decdigit.txt
```

It fails out because I'm guessing, it is loading the 6 and the blank characters etc from the file at which point it can't decrement the "count" variable as it's not just a numeric value.. I've gotten it to return just the digit originally read in.. or it will return "echo off" or various other things depending on what I try..

What I'm looking for is either just enough code to get just the number loaded and decremented, or if you can think of a better way to extract and change the IP address without all the steps I'm using.. that would work as well.. I'm also not overly familiar with any of the code listed above having simply cribbed it from other answers on there.. so maybe I'm just missing something simple as none of it make as whole lot of sense to me.

Answer (score 3):

FOR /F can directly process the output of a command. You can set the delims to a dot and a space so you can parse out the correct tokens in one step.

Note that FINDSTR "IP Address" will match lines that contain "IP" or "Address". You need the `/C:string` option if you want to look for a string literal that includes a space. (It may not matter in this case, but it is good to be aware)

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f "tokens=3-6 delims=. " %%A in (
  '"netsh interface ip show config name=15|findstr /c:"IP Address""'
) do (
  set "beg=%%A.%%B.%%C."
  set /a "end=%%D-1"
)
set "new=%beg%%end%"
echo new=%new%
```

Comment: +1 Note to the OP: Just commenting here that the name option works here when using the full connection name, as in `name="local area connection 2"`

Comment: This worked fine after changing "end=%%D+1" too "end=%%D-1"
Though I am a bit less clear on the variables in this version than the one posted below.  Presumably the findstr command would return a line stating:
"IP Address   xx.xx.xx.xx"
I'm not sure where it strips just the address out, nor why the initial for command states tokens-3-6 when delims=.  seems like that would give  IP Address xx  as the first result  then each of the last 3 numbers as the next 3.. 
Anyway, this works weather I understood it or not, so thank you for your time as well.

Comment: @user2939377 - What happens if last digit is already 0? Shouldn't the "decrement" loop around and set the new value to 255? Regarding how answer works: I set the token delimiters to dot and space, so tokens become "IP", "Address:", "part1", "part2", "part3", "part4". So you want the 3rd through 6th tokens.

Comment: As far as decrementing the IP address, the batch is being used to set a route based on the IP address of an OpenVPN TAP Adapter.. As such 1 and 0 are both out of range as they are assigned to the server.  Every host will get an IP address and also an unseen gateway which I've no idea how to access, but it's always one less than the TAP adapter, which in this case is always adapter 15 as it's based off an image on a cloud service so the adapter number never changes, but the IP differs depending on the order the nodes are launched in.

Answer (score 0):

try removing the %'s around the count in the set first, If that doesn't work, comment and I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ( '"netsh interface ip show config | findstr "IP Adress""' ) do (
    SET IP_DIGITS=%%a
    SET IP_DIGITS=!IP_DIGITS: =!
    echo Old IP Address: !IP_DIGITS!
    for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=." %%b in ( "!IP_DIGITS!" ) DO ( 
        set /a NEW_DIGIT=%%e-1
        ECHO New IP Address %%b.%%c.%%d.!NEW_DIGIT! 
    ECHO.
    )
)
```

Comment: I edited this slightly to only check adapter 15:
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ( '"netsh interface ip show config name=15 | findstr "IP Adress""' )
And it worked great.  I assume the statement tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=." %%B is telling it there are 4 values to be had and too start with %%b since you already used %%a to hold the original address?  Not sure what "set IP_Digits==!IP_Digits!: =! accomplishes but again, it worked out fine and was much cleaner than my aweful attempt with all the file I/O.. THanks.

Comment: @user2939377 - **SET IP_DIGITS=!IP_DIGITS: =!** is used to remove spaces from the output of the command. And regarding **tokens=1,2,3,4**, you will find your answers in the FOR help.